# Determining bots in website

Tags: asp.net, bots

For the security of my website, is there any way I can distinguish between bots and human visitors on my website?

Comment: And also for security. I also need to prevent the DDos attack

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If a bot WANT to be recognized as a bot, yes you can. Example: search engines bots, like Googlebots.

BUT it's extremely easy for a bot do identify himself as a normal browser; then youre stuck.

If you want a list of bots, here you go: http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this might be to check for the `User-Agent` sent in the HTTP request by the current client.

Some bots do not specify any or specifies a specific one such as *GoogleBot* (Googlebot, Mozilla/5.0) or *Baidu Spider*.

There is also a list maintained by [useragentstring](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) which lists all the known user-agents used by various bots, automated scripts or browsers.